# EmailComposerTask - how to detect if email wasn't sent?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm using EmailComposerTask to send an email.
Is there any way to detect if email wasn't sent for problems like no connection, invalid email setting, mail server temporary down etc ?
I cannot find any way get this information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible. Tasks in WP7 consists of launchers and choosers, the EmailComposerTask is one of the launchers which is defined as being:

> A “fire and forget” action, where a specific Windows Phone functionality is launched, for example, sending an SMS message, opening a webpage, or placing a phone call

There is no way to know the result of the action you launched. [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg266434)

Comment: Is there any alternative to EmailComposerTask?

Comment: You cannot access the e-mail accounts set-up on the phone without using the EmailComposerTask. If you really want to you can try to implement your own emailsender but you will never have access to a user's e-mail account. See for example [this tutorial](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1074-how-to-send-an-email-in-silverlight-part-1-.aspx) on sending e-mail from silverlight. I am not sure if it will work on WP7 though

Comment: Thanks for the description. It seems I have to wait two major releases to have something which is 'production ready'. Sending email from lab/dev environment always work but it's quite different story in real life.